# Cannot change ownership of drive because it is read-only (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, permissions, read-only, ownership

My secondary drive suddently became read-only. When I try to remove the read-only (right-click -> Properties -> Untick "Read-only" -> "Apply changes to this folder, subfolders and files), it switches right back to being read-only. In the process, it tells me that a bunch of the files are "media write protected".

I searched online and I found out that it was because I only had the read access as a User. When I try changing it so that my user has the right to modify (Right click -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Users -> Edit -> Full Control -> Ok), it spawns a dialog for every single file in the drive telling me that the media is write protected.

If I try to change the owner of the drive (Right click -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Change (next to user) -> Write Users -> Ok), it has the same result.

I tried some command lines that I found online:

- `D:\>attrib  /d /s -h -r -s`
- `icacls "D:/" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C`
- `icacls "D:/" /setowner "Users" /T /C`

The `attrib` printed `Unable to change attribute - [filename]`([filename being the full path of the file) for all the files in my drive.

The `icacls` printed `[filename]: The media is write protected`. It ended by printing `Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 130716`

Some more details:

- I don't have `Controlled folder access` turned on
- My disk is in NTFS
- Windows is not installed on it
- It is an HDD

I feel like I am in a vicious circle where I need to have the write access to my drive to be able to remove the read-only, but I can't have write access because my files are read only.

I'm running out of ideas/resources. Does anyone knows how to fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `diskpart` to clear the volume or disk read-only attribute.

Open an administrative command prompt.

Enter the following commands:

1. `diskpart`.
2. `list disk`
3. `select disk #` and replace `#` with the number of the disk that is write protected.
4. `attributes disk clear readonly`
5. `list volume`
6. `select volume #` and replace `#` with the number of the volume that is write protected.
7. `attributes volume clear readonly`
8. `exit`
9. `exit`

Try writing to the disk again.

Comment: I tried the above and got 
```DiskPart has encountered an error: A device which does not exist was specified.
See the System Event Log for more information.```

Comment: @DIGIByte When you `list disk` and `list volume` you need to reference the number of the disk and volume in question in the subsequent steps.

Comment: I am aware, I believe the hardware (disk) is broken, the disk shows up on fresh start up but eventually times out or disconnects if I interact with it too much.  even if the disk does not show with list disk, I can select and interact with it, but the volume itself was broken. but this is the result of a few days trying to fix it. if anyone else has this issue, further debugging is needed as tables or sectors maybe broken.